# Is there a way to see the exact numerical wear values of guns on the Steam Community Market?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, steam-community-market

Is there a way to see the wear values of guns on the Steam Community Market? To clarify, I'm not talking about the label qualities (Fac New, Min Wear, FT, BS, WW), I'm talking about a numerical value between `0.99 - 0.00` that decides how "nice" the skin looks.

I know CSGO lounge and CSGO analyst have it, but is there a way to see the wear values of skins on the CSGO community Market?

Comment: You could try looking at [this Reddit PSA post](http://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensiveTrade/comments/2u04mu/psa_how_to_check_your_weapons_exact_wear_values/) but it'll be tedious as you'll have to manually check one-by-one... Unless there's a browser plugin or something that can do it for you. _But the problem with that is that items placed onto the market won't appear in the seller's inventory or .json copy of their inventory... Which is a bit of a problem, when it comes to answering your problem..._

Comment: @aytimothy the reason for this question is that item inspection is very misleading. you can inspect it and have it look amazing visually, but later learn either the wear value is really low (and then you realize that comparing it to the same skin with a better wear makes your skin look much duller), or that there's scratches you didn't notice in inspection (backside of weapons, etc).

Comment: As far as I know - There isn't any API you can call that I've heard of that lists the items on the market (for a specific item) in the same manner of retrieving inventory items. Also, you might try asking your question on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) since they do "cover" that topic [aparently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/steam-web-api).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csgo.exchange is a good website for that. Sign in with steam, go to the inspect page for the item, and copy the link to inspect the weapon in game. Go to the home page of the website, you should see "Steam Market Float". That'll tell you everything you know.

Answer (score 1):

[glws.org](https://glws.org) is probably the best site for a short inspection of a certain gun from the steam market. Just copy the inspect link and paste it.